# Limit of recurrent sequence, two possible outcomes

Tags: limits

I am trying to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{(a_{n})}$ where $a_0 \ge 5, a_{n+1}=a_n^2-10a_n+30$. The usual way to do this is to notice that if $a_n \to g$, then $a_{n+1} \to g$. From this $a_n^2-10a_n+30 \to g^2-10g+30$ and comparing the two limits yields $g=g^2-10g+30$. The problem is, I get two possible limits $g_1=5, g_2=6$. How can I decide which is the right one before trying to show that the sequence is monotonic (at least for large $n$s)?

Comment: Depending on $a_0\geqslant5$, the sequence can converge to $5$, or be stationary at $6$, or go to infinity. Note that $$a_{n+1}-5=(a_n-5)^2$$ hence $$a_n-5=(a_0-5)^{2^n}$$

Comment: You first need to prove it converges (by monotonicity for example) before taking the limit. In your case, if $a_0 \in \{5,6\}$ then $a_n = a_0$ for $\forall n \ge 1$ so the limit is not univocally defined by the given conditions alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\geq 0$,

$$a_{n+1}-5=a_n^2-10a_n+25$$

$$=(a_n-5)^2$$

$$=(a_{n-1}-5)^4$$

.

.

$$=(a_0-5)^{2^{n+1}}.$$

thus

$$4<a_0<6 \implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=5$$

$$a_0=4  \implies \lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=6$$

$$a_0=6 \implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=6$$

$$a_0>6 \implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=+\infty$$

$$a_0<4 \implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=+\infty.$$